# How can I make Resharper stop Javascript autocompleting $ as '$t?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, resharper

When I call jQuery methods like jQuery.ajax I use $.ajax. Resharper is picking up something from jqGrid's code that makes it want to autocomplete $t whenever I type $. Its making jQuery coding REALLY slow - does anyone know how I can disable that?

**UPDATE**

I know its possible to totally suspend Resharper from Tools -> Options -> Resharper -> General -> Suspend, but I really just want it to leave my javscript alone ;(

Comment: Could you include in the text of your question which versions of Resharper, jQuery, jqGrid and jQuery UI you use?

Comment: I use ReSharper 6.0 (6.0.2202.688), jqGrid 4.2.0, jQuery UI 1.8.16 and jQuery 1.6.4 or 1.7RC1 and can't reproduce the described problem. Only `$` is known and no `$t`.

Comment: I get `$e` instead of `$t`. Resharper picks it up from jquery.corners.js ... Resharper also picks up other jQuery methods from jQuery plugins instead of jQuery proper. I'd like to be able to tell Resharper to give jQuery.js highest priority, or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that somewhere in your code or in the code of jqGrid the *global* variable `$t` are defined. The code of jqGrid has many places like

```
methodName: function (methodParameters) {
    return this.each(function () {
        var $t = this, ...
        ...
    });
}
```

So there are many places where *local* variable `$t` are defined. Inside of other methods you will see `var t = this` or `var ts = this` or `var self = this` and so on.

So I suppose, that somewhere in the code of jqGrid which you use there are cup & pasted error: one copied the code from the function having `var $t = this` defined in the other method where one used another variable name to save `this`. So the `$t` will be interpret as global variable.

I recommend you to find the definition of the `$t` in your code. Just press <kbd>F12</kbd> on `$t` or use another possibilities of Resharper to find where the *global* `$t` variable are defined.

Comment: Changing the suggested method cures the symptom, not the disease. If I correct the `$e` that Resharper suggests, it just finds another global variable starting with `$` from any number of other jQuery plugins referenced in my solution.

Comment: @MattCasto: I wrote in the answer only my assumptions because I *can't reproduce the problem* on my version of ReSharper 6 and jqGrid. So I have no global `$t` or `$e` variables defined somewhere. Could you provide a demo which reproduce your problem? Which version of jqGrid, jQuery and jQuery UI you use? Which other plugins you use? Do you use `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` or `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`?

Comment: I was able to reproduce similar behavior, with the `$e` variable, using jQuery corners 0.3. I think you might be able to get behavior like this just by creating a global variable that starts with dollar sign `$` in any JS file in the solution, and Resharper will pick it up. However, I haven't tested this myself.

Comment: @MattCasto: You don't answered on my questions from the previous comment. **Which version of jqGrid, jQuery and jQuery UI you use? Do you use jquery.jqGrid.src.js or jquery.jqGrid.min.js? Which version of ReSharper you use?** I tried with ReSharper 6.0 and 6.1 and has no problems. I can't reproduce the problem because if I type `$` on the top level the context menu suggest only `$ (in jQuery....js)`.

Comment: I'm using ReSharper 6.1. My particular site uses jQuery 1.5 and jQuery UI 1.8.9 customized, but its not referenced in my solution so I don't know whether Resharper picks it up. I don't use jqGrid.

Comment: @MattCasto: If you press F12  over `$e` the definition of the `$e` should be shown. What you see? If it will not help you can try to create new solution in Visual Studio with new empty web project. Then include jQuery 1.5 (non-minimized version) and try to reproduce the problem with `$e`. Then you can add one more JavaScript file and  verify the existence of the problem with `$e` one more time till you will have the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In lack of a true solution, a better work around would be to define the `$` function in a common.js file in your solution.

```
$ = $;
```

This doesn't fix the issue with the `$t` or whatever other global method you see (`$e` in my case) but it should suggest the `$` from your common.js file as the top suggestion.

I like this work around a bit more than modifying the offending jQuery plugin source files because I don't want to have to re-apply this modification every time I update my plugins. Also, I don't have to worry about possibly breaking anything by changing variable names or eliminating global variables.